# Converter String em tabelas

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
local items = {}
local t = "7 2182, 4 2554, 5 9908"
```

eu queria converter usando essa string e deixar a tabela sair assim:

```
local items = {{7,2182},{4,2554},{5,9908}}
```

será que tem algum jeito? usando gsub talvez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente o código abaixo:

```
local items = {}
local t = "7 2182, 4 2554, 5 9908"
local n = 0
for a,b in t:gmatch("(%d+)%s+(%d+)") do
        n = n + 1
        items[n] = {a,b}
end
for k,v in ipairs(items) do print(k,v[1],v[2]) end
```

O padrão em `t:gmatch` captura duas sequências de dígitos separadas por espaços.

Comment: Solução semelhante à solução em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710798/convert-table-string-to-the-actual-table.

Comment: Também dá com gsub(): `t:gsub(pattern, fn)` (enfim, acho que não faz muita diferença no tamanho).